# HttpListener multiple connections fails

Tags: c#, httplistener

I'm trying to open a connection in C# to the server through 5 or 6 tabs, simultaneously.

The first connection works.

The others hang (the browser is `waiting`)

```
public class HtServer {
    HttpListener HL = new HttpListener();

    public void startServer(){
        HL.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:800/");
        HL.Start();
        IAsyncResult HLC = HL.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(clientConnection),HL);
    }

    public static void clientConnection(IAsyncResult res){
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)res.AsyncState;
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(res);
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        // Obtain a response object.
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
        // Construct a response. 
        string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world! " + DateTime.Now + "</BODY></HTML>";
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        // You must close the output stream.
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        output.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use port 800?

Comment: do you release your thread anywhere? This may block : `HLC.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();`

Comment: @KhanhTO yes, this was a temp' test, included in the question by mistake

Comment: @HamletHakobyan no reason. trying to avoid problems with apache and other servers on the machine

Comment: Looking at MSDN description of HttListener, I can conclude, that you should instantiate `HttpListerner` at every your call of method `startServer()`. So, your `HL` should not be public, and upgrade `startServer()` with static.

Comment: The answer is in your other question.